# comparing GUID/UUIDs in javascript

Tags: javascript, uuid, guid

I have a function that is supposed to filter out messages without the same UUID in javascript.  However when comparing, nothing is equal, even the ones that clearly are.  They are all lowercase on both sides and when you console log they come out looking identical.

**Interesting detail that might lead to whats wrong. I cannot use the trim function on first guid without some kind of string conversion first**

```
function filterReceivedMessages()
    {
        var neededMessages = [];
        for(var i=0; i < messages.length; i++)
        {
            if((messages[i].orginator+"").trim() != client.GetUserUid().trim())
            {                   
                neededMessages.push(messages[i]);
            }
        }
        return neededMessages;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the `messages` variable?

Comment: Don't think it should make a difference, but I would call `client.getUserUid().trim()` just once and put it in a variable. Then use `messages.filter()`.

Comment: Your code does the opposite of what you say you want. It filters out the UIDs that are the same as `client.GetUserUid()`, not the ones that are different.

Comment: Other than that, I don't see anything obviously wrong. Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you. Storing them in a variable before comparing fixed this issue.  Strange... but thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, unless `client.GetUserUid()` returns a different value each time you call it.